# grep -v -A not working properly (actually not working at all)

Tags: macos, grep, pipe

I have to filter lines like the following:

```
[javac] /Users/looris/Sviluppo/android/projects/toutry/src/net/looris/toutry/Stuff.java:23: warning: unmappable character for encoding ascii
[javac]             return (poked=false); // NOTA: è un'assegnazione, non un controllo!
[javac]                                                ^
```

I've tried `|grep -v -A2 "unmappable character for encoding ascii"` but it just does nothing.

If I just do `|grep -v "unmappable character for encoding ascii"` it *does* filter that line, but I need to filter the following two lines too.

(using "grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1" under OSX 10.5)

Comment: I don't think you can mix `-v` and `-A` but You should be able to use `sed` or `awk` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `grep -A2 -v`, it will start to skip lines if there are more then 2 lines righ after each other that contains the search pattern, which is obviously not what you want. Try this:

```
| awk 'BEGIN { skip = 0 } /unmappable character for encoding ascii/ { skip = 3 } { if (skip > 0) { skip-- } else { print $0 } }'
```

The AWK code expanded:

```
BEGIN { 
    skip = 0
}
/unmappable character for encoding ascii/ { 
    skip = 3
}
{ 
    if (skip > 0) { 
        skip--
    } else { 
        print $0
    } 
}
```

Comment: unfortunatly this method has the problem of killing the return value. Any solution?

Comment: well, a workaround:

if ($COMPILE) {
 $CE=xsys('ant debug>/tmp/antdebug.out');
 xsys('cat /tmp/antdebug.out| awk \'BEGIN { skip = 0 } /unmappable character for encoding ascii/ { skip = 3 } { if (skip > 0) { skip-- } else { print $0 } }\'');
 $CE and diex("Compile error");
}